# How does python operator precedence work with double comparisons?

Tags: python, operator-precedence, comparison-operators

`-3<-2<-1` returns `True`.

However I would expect it interpreted as

```
(-3<-2)<-1
True<-1
1<-1
False
```

How is that possible ?

Comment: This is how Python works. One of the many great features of this language if you ask me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). Instead of being left-associative like `(-3 < -2) < -1` or right-associative like `-3 < (-2 < -1)`, it's actually treated as

```
(-3 < -2) and (-2 < -1)
```

except that `-2` is evaluated at most once.

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Unlike C, expressions like `a < b < c` have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
>   to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be `false`).

Therefore

```
-3 < -2 < -1
```

is equivalent to

```
-3 < -2 and -2 < -1  # where -2 is evaluated only once
```

Answer (score 0):

It's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) that it is part of the language